# How to allow standard user to install software in Sierra?

Tags: security

Thank you in advance for the wealth of knowledge on this site.  I am setting up a new MacBook Pro with Sierra and need to ensure the standard user account is able to install software and make changes to printing.  Besides these two items it needs to be a standard account.  With the research I have done it seems the **security authorizationdb** would be used however I am unsure on how to use this command correctly.  Can someone please advise on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

There is this [jamf post](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/14919/system-preferences-for-standard-users). The solution there is to tweak 1th. the authorisation database an 2th. allow standard users to add/remove printers by adding them to the lpadmin group.

1. 

`security authorizationdb write system.preferences allow`

`security authorizationdb write system.preferences.printing allow`

2. 

`dseditgroup -o edit -a $username -t user lpadmin`

Refs:
[JAMF](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/14919/system-preferences-for-standard-users)
[DSSW](http://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/authorization-rights/index.html)

[terminal](/questions/tagged/terminal) [macos](/questions/tagged/macos)